# Is the matrix exponential of a system of linear differential equations the fundamental matrix of that system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A fundamental matrix of a system of n homogeneous linear ordinary
>   differential equations
>
> \begin{equation} \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = A(t) \mathbf{x}(t)
> > \end{equation}
>
> is a matrix-valued function  $\Psi(t)$  whose columns are linearly
>   independent solutions of the system.     -Wikipedia

Now, I also know that the system has solution $\mathbf{x}=e^{At}\mathbf{x}(0)$. The columns of this matrix are linearly independent. Does this mean one can use $e^{At}$ as a fundamental matrix?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Even when you ommit the $\vec{x}(0)$?

Comment: If you do not omit $x(0)$ you will have a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: So, more generally, is it right to say that the GENERAL solution to $\vec{x}'=A\vec{x}$ is just $e^{At}\vec{c}$, where $\vec{c}$ are arbitrary constants? Or is this only useful when the condition $\vec{x}(0)$ is explicitly given?

Comment: You are correct again, "it is right to say"

Comment: No, it is only correct if the matrix function $A(t)$ is actually constant. In general, one can formally write the solution as time-ordered exponential, but as the name says, this is a much more complicated formula.

Comment: @LutzL which statement are you referring to?

Comment: That you can generally solve $y'(t)=A(t)y(t)$ using the matrix exponential, as the question in combination of quote and follow-up stated. For that you need that $A(s)$ and $A(t)$ commute for all $s,t$, which is the case for $A(t)=A=const.$.